# Notify others if a question is already solved on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I posted a question on Stack Overflow. And already solved it with the help of another user. How to notify everyone that the question is already solved?

Comment: I feel there is some debate if this handles on self-answering questions.

Comment: There is no "solved" here. Did you mean "has accepted answer"? If so, then this is already pretty well visible. And who is "everyone" you want to notice?

Answer (score 2):

There is a checkmark below the voting bar of all answers to your question. Go to the answer that worked for you and Click it to accept the answer and everybody will understand you have found your answer. See : [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Maybe add a link to http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @rene I don't think the op is talking about self answers

Comment: Hmmm, then you're reading the question different than I am.

Comment: @rene Maybe but the OP said `I post a question in stackoverflow. And already solved it by the help of **other user**`

Comment: But the OP solved it, not the other user was my line of reasoning. But I'm fine wth your answer, I already deleted mine that was more on the self-answer track....

Comment: @rene I guess the OP will clarify that